# How to check existence of web appln entry in sharepoint_confg DB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, content-database

I want to check the existence for a specific entry in the sharepoint_config database . Previosuly  i have created a web appln and its content db , and now i removed both.

How will I come to know whether there exist an entry for this web appln in SP config or not. I mean , i need to find out the **orphaned entries**  from the sp config db. <>p>
is there any powershell script which does this ?